# Search file contents in Google Drive containing '@' symbol from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to search Google Drive for various file types (txt, csv, xls) that look like they contain email addresses.

So I've tried using variations of the search files query below:

```
files  = DriveApp.searchFiles
(
    ' ('+
        ' (mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") OR' +
        ' (mimeType = "text/xml") OR' +
        ' (mimeType = "text/csv") OR' +
        ' (mimeType = "text/plain") OR' +
        ' (mimeType = "application/octet-stream")' +
    ' )' +
' and' +
    ' ('+
        ' (fullText contains \'"@"\') '+
    ' )'
);
```

However, it seems that the 'fullText' part of the search is picking up the @ from the user / file owner field as it is simply returning every file with the specified Mime types whether the actual file content contains an @ symbol or not.

If I alter the fulltext part of the query to "(NOT fullText contains \'"my.email@domain.com"\')" then it includes files of the expected type that are not owned / modified by me - I only see files that are owned by other users on my domain.

So my question is, is there a way to exclude the username field from being included in the fullText part of the file search so that it only searches the actual file contents for an @ symbol? Or what is another way that I could search Google Drive for file contents that look like they contain email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files) for `searchFiles`'s parameters, I noticed they did don't signal a way to specifically look into the content alone, `fullText` seems to be the only way to approach the content, but it includes all the other details, as specified [in this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-files)

A possible workaround would be to evaluate the files individually, but I suspect this is what the extension did, since it would explain why it took so long. alternatively, you could try to search for a `' @ '`, if the spaces are present it could not be an email address, which would ignore the writers/editors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alberto, the problem I have is that I actually want to find email addresses so searching for ' @ ' unfortunately won't return the email addresses I need to find. I've been working on a work around based on reading each file individually, but that has some of its own problems too (I am unable to read files contents larger than 50 Mb for instance).

Comment: Did the extension work with these larger files? because if so then there might be a workaround from just checking the files like that.

Comment: @richelectron Hi, after some more testing, I reported this behavior in Google Issue Tracker, you can follow the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138195238).

Comment: When you mention 'the extension', what extension do you mean? Could you please clarify? Also thank you for your investigation and for reporting the issue to Google, that's very kind of you!

Comment: @richelectron Sorry about the extension comment, I was under the impression that you had used one, must have been thinking of something else. And no problem! you can check in that link for updates.